# Why does the vertical space between desktop icons change when I toggle the auto hide property of the taskbar?

Tags: taskbar, desktop-icons

I recently changed the auto-hide property of of my taskbar from "On" to "Off". Doing so caused all the icons on my desktop to get rearranged. The icons were rearranged in such a way as to clear out the bottom-most row.

Even with the bottom-most clearded out, if I toggle the taskbar between "Auto Hide On" and "Auto Hide Off" the vertical space between desktop icons changes a little. It appears that when in the "Off" state the vertical space between each row of icons is smaller. When the state is "On" the vertical space between each row of icons is greater.

Can someone explain to me what is happening and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows does this because you have "Align icons to Grid" turned on.

You can toggle it by

- Right-clicking anywhere on the Desktop
- *XP:* Arrange Icons by -> Align to Grid
- *Vista+:* View -> Align icons to grid.

Comment: I had no idea about that... thanks. Your answer lead me to a nice article about [advanced desktop settings](http://www.geekyramblings.net/2004/08/24/windows-xp-desktop-grid/).